# Spark difference or conflicts between setMaster in app conf and --master flag on sparkSubmit

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm trying to understand the importance of setting the master property when running a spark application.

The cluster location is at the default port of 7077.  I'm running this app from a  testmachine where it will hit an s3 bucket.

Currently spark configuration in the app reads:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
.setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")
```

but I'm also setting the flag on the command line with spark submit:

```
--master spark://127.0.0.1:7077
```

So, does having both of these set cause problems?  Does one get overridden by the other?  Are they both necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, does having both of these set cause problems? Does one get
>   overridden by the other? Are they both necessary?

The [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) page is very clear (emphasis mine):

> Any values specified as flags or in the properties file will be passed
>   on to the application and merged with those specified through
>   SparkConf. **Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest
>   precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then
>   options in the spark-defaults.conf file.** A few configuration keys have
>   been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older
>   key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any
>   instance of the newer key.

Comment: So, this is kind of dumb - I'm setting the SparkConf in the app to 7077 so i'm expecting that, as the sc, to override all other values as it's the highest up the food chain, yet if I remove my flag from sparksubmit and set to cluster I receive an error telling me it's not available on master local.  If I set the flag to 7077 it works as expected.  So does 'properties set directly on the SparnConf' not relate to those set in app?

Comment: @null By "set to cluster" you mean running spark submit in deploy mode cluster?