# Spark: ERROR Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive

Tags: apache-spark

I have a problem trying to run an application in a spark cluster called `mymaster` (and I've checked the name in the config file, to be sure).

I've been running the app using the following:

`spark-submit --master spark://mymaster:7077 ...`

But the thing is I didn't realized my code had the following lines in the driver:

```
val master = parameters.getOrElse("master", "local[*]")
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp").setMaster(master)
val sc   = new SparkContext(conf)
```

So I wanted to delete the `.setMaster(master)` part because I thought "it is unnecesary". I did it and I got the following error:

```
ERROR cluster.StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
```

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36197126/9759150 says:

> Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file.

But if I try putting only this:

```
val master = parameters.getOrElse("master", "spark://hadoop-master:7077")
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp").setMaster(master)
```

I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the code.

It is recommended don't set master using `.setMaster(aMaster)` but spark-shell using `--master aMaster`.

But the error message was due to the Spark cluster was down in that moment.